# Replace all values in a data.table given a condition

Tags: r, data.table

How would you replace all values in a data.table given a condition?

For example

```
ppp <- data.table(A=1:6,B=6:1,C=1:6,D=3:8)

A B C D
1 6 1 3
2 5 2 4
3 4 3 5
4 3 4 6
5 2 5 7
6 1 6 8
```

I want to replace all "6" by NA

```
A B C D
1 NA 1 3
2 5 2 4
3 4 3 5
4 3 4 NA
5 2 5 7
NA 1 6 8
```

I've tried something like

```
ppp[,ifelse(.SD==6,NA,.SD)]
```

but it doesn't work, it produces a much wider table.

Comment: You should probably be using a matrix if this is the sort of thing you need to do.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A native `data.table` way to do this would be:

```
for(col in names(ppp)) set(ppp, i=which(ppp[[col]]==6), j=col, value=NA)
# Test
> ppp
    A  B  C  D
1:  1 NA  1  3
2:  2  5  2  4
3:  3  4  3  5
4:  4  3  4 NA
5:  5  2  5  7
6: NA  1 NA  8
```

This approach - while perhaps more verbose - is nevertheless going to be significantly faster than `ppp[ppp == 6] <- NA`, because it avoids the copying of all columns.

Comment: Nice.  Any way to write it without an explicit for?

Comment: It is necessary to loop over the columns.

Comment: What if instead of having a single number (like "6")  I had a vector with different numbers for different columns?.  For example I say columns c(2,5,6,9,11,111) must be compared against c(==6,==6, >1, >0, ==21,==2)

Comment: I don't know why but in my computer, with a much bigger real data.table, it takes almost the same time to do it with your looping set() than with the ppp[ppp == 6] <- NA  way, 63sec vs 74sec.

Comment: @skan perhaps this will work (from `purrr` package): `iwalk(ppp, ~set(ppp, i = which(.x == 6), j = .y, value = NA))`

Answer (score 19):

Even easier:

```
ppp[ppp == 6] <- NA

 ppp
    A  B  C  D
1:  1 NA  1  3
2:  2  5  2  4
3:  3  4  3  5
4:  4  3  4 NA
5:  5  2  5  7
6: NA  1 NA  8
```

Importantly, this doesn't change its class:

```
is.data.table(ppp)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: There's also `is.na(ppp) <- ppp == 6`

Comment: Thanks. I used that just yesterday, but seem to fall back into bad habits.

Comment: Anyway to assign the NA from inside the brackets?.  When I see data.table examples usually everything done within the brackets is done with data.table and is faster than any operation done outside, isn't it?.

Comment: @skan You are right, generally. In this case, you might instead use `set`, though, which also modifies by reference. Something like `for (col in seq_along(ppp)) set(ppp, i = which(is.na(ppp[[col]])), j = col, v = NA)`. See mtoto's answer.

Comment: @skan. This should be about as fast as anything else except maybe `set`. I suspect the speed differences there will come down to data size as this method does involve a copy.

Comment: I like this solution but how to use it for only a subset of columns?

Comment: @HermanToothrot The beauty of this answer is the brevity. For a subset of columns, it's probably easier to use the method in mtoto's answer. Just use a subset of the column names in the `for` loop.